# Something wrong with how I'm bundling rasterio into an executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rasterio

### Expected behavior and actual behavior.

I expected to compile a script using `rasterio` into an executable using `pyinstaller`.  The script runs fine from within my python environment. However I am not able to freeze it into an executable using `PyInstaller`.

### Steps to reproduce the problem.

I have a script called `workflow_3.py` which contains the following:

`import rasterio`

That's it. I tried to compile then run this using  pyinstaller as follows:

`(wps_env36) D:\11202750-002_RA2CE\Basis>pyinstaller workflow_3.py
(wps_env36) D:\11202750-002_RA2CE\Basis>dist\workflow_3\workflow_3.exe`

The compilation seems to run to completion, however when I run the executable I get the following error:

```
(wps_env36) D:\11202750-002_RA2CE\Basis>dist\workflow_3\workflow_3.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workflow_3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rasterio
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_i
mporters.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "rasterio\_base.pyx", line 1, in init rasterio._base
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio._shim'
[17536] Failed to execute script workflow_3
```

### Attempt to fix the problem

I modified the spec file  by explicitly adding `'rasterio._shim'` to the list contained by the `hidden-imports` variable.  Then I ran `pyinstaller workflow_3.spec` . This caused other `ModuleNotFoundError` for modules such as `control`.py, `crs.py` and `vrt.py`.

Adding these to `hidden-imports` successfully eliminates the `ModuleNotFoundError` 
 for that particular package but it still looks for other packages, all of which are contained in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\Lib\site-packages\rasterio`. There are about 40 modules in this directory. It seems excessive to add every single filename in this directory to the `hidden-imports` variable. In fact I don't even know if it would work.

Therefore, I also tried adding that whole directory into my `pathex` variable so that it can extend the `PYTHONPATH` with it. However this causes another problem:

`File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\tokenize.py", line 27, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'open'
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.`

### Operating system

Windows 7

### Rasterio version and provenance

The rasterio version is 1.0.8, from conda-forge
The python version is 3.6.6

I have two versions of pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller               3.4              py36h7602738_0    conda-forge
PyInstaller               3.5.dev0+b13e6b30b           <pip>
```

The second one is the development version, which I had to get because of [this problem](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3750)

### Question

How do I use `PyInstaller` to freeze an application which uses `rasterio`?

Comment: Could anyone help? What other information can I provide that would make this question easier to answer?

Comment: I think you will just have to wait till someone knows the answer. People will tell you if they miss some information.

Comment: Sometimes people won't unless you ask. Anyhow it never hurts to to check...

Comment: I have a very similar issue, currently trying your solution with little luck. Will post if I find another solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current solution that I came up with is to force feed `hidden-imports` variable all modules contained within `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\Lib\sitepackages\rasterio` using the `glob` package. In my spec file I added some python code to do this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None
import glob, os
rasterio_imports_paths = glob.glob(r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\*.py')
rasterio_imports = ['rasterio._shim']

for item in rasterio_imports_paths:
    current_module_filename = os.path.split(item)[-1]
    current_module_filename = 'rasterio.'+current_module_filename.replace('.py', '')
    rasterio_imports.append(current_module_filename)

a = Analysis(['workflow_3.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\11202750-002_RA2CE\\Basis'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=rasterio_imports,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='workflow_3',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='workflow_3')
```

Unfortunately this does not explain why `pyinstaller` was not able to see those modules in the first place. However it does momentarily solve this problem, and the code compiles fine.

Comment: did you install pywin32 in addition to pyinstaller? It is available as a pypi package https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32 According to the pyinstaller docs, this should automatically be installed as a dependency, but I had problems with it in the past and a manual installation solved them

Comment: What makes you think this is pywin32 related?

Comment: Just a guess. And the error message you got: "ImportError: cannot import name 'open'
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing." That is extremely similar to the mine

Answer (score 2):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1707786/13756780) to avoid hard-coding rasterio's install path like user32882 did, so the spec file can work on any OS. The rest of the method is the same:

```
import pkgutil

import rasterio

# list all rasterio and fiona submodules, to include them in the package
additional_packages = list()
for package in pkgutil.iter_modules(rasterio.__path__, prefix="rasterio."):
    additional_packages.append(package.name)


block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['src\\main.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=additional_packages,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='myProgram',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='myProgram')
```

I tested that this method also works with [Fiona](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/), which has the same issue with PyInstaller.