# Issue in converting .py file to .exe file using pyinstaller python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am having following python file named "test.py" containing:

```
import rasterio
import rioxarray
import xarray
import gdal
import geopandas
import pandas
import fiona
import shapely
from pyproj import _datadir, datadir
from fiona import _shim, schema

print("All Imported Successfully")
```

Then I have used "pyinstaller --onefile test.py" command to create test.exe file.

Post this after incorporating the suggestions mentioned in the stack overflow links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149750/something-wrong-with-how-im-bundling-rasterio-into-an-executable) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662773/cannot-import-geopandas-with-pyinstaller-executable-despite-running-fine-in-th),
I am trying to get exe file which would run successfully.

I had modified my test.spec ([spec file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Reg1pDLfLcVsj9iDyQxEfMvXVKqpUbM/view?usp=sharing)) file accordingly and then run "pyinstaller test.spec" command. But after running this command I am getting following output in command prompt and my test.exe file is not getting modified (which was created after running the first command "pyinstaller --onefile test.py"):

```
1573 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
1573 INFO: Python: 3.8.5 (conda)
1573 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
1573 INFO: UPX is not available.
1589 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\Projects\\S5P_NC_Files',
 'D:\\Projects\\S5P_NC_Files',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\Library\\bin']
2057 INFO: checking Analysis
2173 INFO: Building because hiddenimports changed
2173 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
2173 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
2204 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5485 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5485 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib'
9829 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10079 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
10095 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\python.exe
10313 INFO: Analyzing test.py
13470 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
13470 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
27612 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
43346 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
46970 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
75503 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio._shim'
75503 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.fill'
75503 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.merge'
75518 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.plot'
75518 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.rpc'
75518 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.sample'
75518 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.tools'
75534 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'rasterio.__init__'
75534 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'geos'
75534 ERROR: Hidden import 'geos' not found
75534 INFO: Processing module hooks...
75534 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-appdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-branca.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75565 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
75831 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77974 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-fiona.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
77974 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-folium.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
78036 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
78708 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80692 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80692 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80723 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80801 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-netCDF4.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80832 WARNING: Hidden import "netcdftime" not found!
80832 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-osgeo.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80864 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80864 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pyproj.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
80895 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81426 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-regex.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-rtree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shapely.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.cluster.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.linear_model.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.metrics.cluster.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.neighbors.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
81957 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.neighbors._typedefs" not found!
82113 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82881 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.tree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82881 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sklearn.utils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
82881 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
83678 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
84021 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84271 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84287 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84287 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84287 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84396 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84396 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84396 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84396 WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!
84412 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'importlib_resources._py2'
84412 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
84459 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85209 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo
85568 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
85959 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk4Agg requires cairo
86318 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
86677 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
87648 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
88257 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtAgg": added
88632 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
89210 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
89585 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
90491 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
91397 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
92006 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
92906 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
93265 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
93624 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
94124 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
94499 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
95514 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
96498 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
97092 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
97623 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
98514 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
102254 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102644 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102644 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102738 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
102785 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102800 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102800 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
103066 INFO: NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
103253 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
103769 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
103785 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
104191 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
104191 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
104222 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
104238 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
105722 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
105768 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
105768 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
107755 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108567 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108645 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109473 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
109848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
112050 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117081 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117081 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117096 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117096 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117096 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117096 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117270 INFO: checking Tree
117349 INFO: checking Tree
117442 INFO: checking Tree
117442 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
117739 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
117927 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
117942 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
117958 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
117973 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
117973 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
117973 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyproj.py'
117973 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_osgeo.py'
118052 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
118864 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_proxy_steerable.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118864 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_device.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118879 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\error.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118879 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118879 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_poll.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118895 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\message.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118895 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_version.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118911 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\context.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
118911 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp38-win_amd64.pyd dependency of C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\utils.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
120707 INFO: Looking for eggs
120707 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\Sentinel-5P\python38.dll
120707 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
120754 INFO: Warnings written to D:\Projects\S5P_NC_Files\build\test\warn-test.txt
121332 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\Projects\S5P_NC_Files\build\test\xref-test.html
121582 INFO: Appending 'binaries' from .spec
Empty DEST not allowed when adding binary and data files. Maybe you want to used '.'.
Caused by 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Sentinel-5P\\Library\\bin\\geos.dll'.
```

Can someone help in resolving this issue.