# In Anaconda how to Use Pyinstaller to freeze an application that uses Rasterio? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio.sample'

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, rasterio

I wrote a python code below in anaconda and have no issues successfully running in through the Spyder IDE.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rioxarray as rxr
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from shapely.geometry import mapping

# Define a function to plot geospatial data
def plot_geospatial_data(geotiff_path, shapefile_path, canvas_elem):
    # Read GeoTIFF and Shapefile
    geotiff = rasterio.open(geotiff_path)
    shapefile = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

    # Create a figure and axis for plotting with a specific size (770 x 400)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10.7, 5.5))

    # Plot the GeoTIFF
    show(geotiff, ax=ax, cmap='summer')
    ax.set_title('GeoTiff/Shapefile Plot')

    # Plot the Shapefile
    shapefile.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor='red', alpha=0.7, legend=True, label='Shapefile')

    # Show the plot on the canvas
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=canvas_elem.Widget)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    return fig

def trim_function(existing_surface_path, fill_boundary_path, output_path_elem):

    # Open the GeoTIFF using rioxarray
    existing_surface = rxr.open_rasterio(existing_surface_path, masked=True).squeeze()

    # Open Shapefile
    aoi = os.path.join(fill_boundary_path)

    # Open crop extent (your study area extent boundary)
    crop_extent = gpd.read_file(aoi)

    # Crop the Existing Surface using rioxarray
    fill_surface = existing_surface.rio.clip(crop_extent.geometry.apply(mapping), crop_extent.crs)

    # Ask the user to select an output file path
    output_path = sg.popup_get_file("Select Output Path", save_as=True, file_types=(("GeoTIFF Files", "*.tif"),))

    # If the user selected an output path, ensure it has a .tif extension
    if output_path:
        if not output_path.endswith(".tif"):
            output_path += ".tif"

        # Export the trimmed surface as a GeoTIFF
        fill_surface.rio.to_raster(output_path, driver="GTiff")

# Define the layout of the GUI window
layout = [

    [sg.Frame("Data Selection", layout=[
        [
            sg.Column([
                [sg.Text("Select a GeoTIFF file: ", font=("Helvetica", 14))],
                [sg.Text("Select a Shapefile file:", font=("Helvetica", 14))],
            ]),
            sg.Column([
                [sg.InputText(key="geotiff_path", size=(60, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("GeoTIFF Files", "*.tif"),))],
                [sg.InputText(key="shapefile_path", size=(60, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Shapefile Files", "*.shp"),))],
            ])
        ]
    ], expand_x=True)],

    [sg.Canvas(key="canvas", background_color="white", size=(770, 400))],

    [sg.Button("Plot Me", size=(10, 1), font=("Helvetica", 14)),
     sg.Text("", size=(95, 1)),  # Spacer
     sg.Button("Export Me", size=(10, 1), font=("Helvetica", 14))
    ]
]

# Create the GUI window
window = sg.Window("CropMe", layout, finalize=True, size=(800, 600))
canvas_elem = window["canvas"]  # Initialize canvas_elem
current_plot = None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Plot Me":
        geotiff_path = values["geotiff_path"]
        shapefile_path = values["shapefile_path"]
        if geotiff_path and shapefile_path:
            if current_plot is not None:
                plt.close(current_plot)
            current_plot = plot_geospatial_data(geotiff_path, shapefile_path, canvas_elem)
    if event == "Export Me":
        geotiff_path = values["geotiff_path"]
        shapefile_path = values["shapefile_path"]
        if geotiff_path and shapefile_path:
            trim_function(geotiff_path, shapefile_path, window)
    
    window.read(timeout=0)  # Force a GUI refresh

window.close()
```

When I attempt to package the code using `pyinstaller` on macOS I do the following steps:

1.) Open the terminal and run the environment: `conda activate Crop_Environment`

2.) Navigate to the location of my python script using the `cd ~/to/python/script`

3.) Run the code to compile the python script using pyinstaller `pyinstaller --onefile Crop_Script.py`

Opening the file it creates in the Terminal yields the following Error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasterio.sample'` 
Why do I receive this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how the rasterio package is laid out. To fix it, either explicitly add `import rasterio.sample` to your script (and iteratively every other rasterio module it will complain about afterwards), or add the rasterio modules as hidden imports to the pyinstaller build `.spec`. See [also this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149750/something-wrong-with-how-im-bundling-rasterio-into-an-executable).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).